# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'OracleConnection'.'

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

The following code uses Entity Framework 6 and Managed Oracle Providers to call an Oracle stored procedure that returns multiple cursors.

The `using` statement is throwing the following exception:

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'OracleConnection'.'
```

If I remove the using statement and instead use the code in the following post. I get no errors.

[Using Entity Framework to Call an Oracle Stored Procedure with Multiple Cursors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208312/using-entity-framework-to-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-with-multiple-cursors)

Why is the using statement causing an exception? It has been suggested to me that there is a bug with the Oracle Managed Provider. But, my colleagues are using the same provider and their using statements are working fine.

**Example Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace MyCompany
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private MyDbContext _dbContext = new MyDbContext();

        public MyItems GetMyItems(string id)
        {
            var sqlQuery = "";
            var oracleParameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
            var oneEntityList = new List<OneEntity>();
            var twoEntityList = new List<TwoEntity>();
            var threeEntityList = new List<ThreeEntity>();

            sqlQuery = @"

BEGIN 

MY_PACKAGE.GetMyItems(:id, :p_cursor1, :p_cursor2, :p_cursor3);

END;

";
            oracleParameters = new List<OracleParameter>
            {
                new OracleParameter("p_id", id),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor2", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output),
                new OracleParameter("p_cursor3", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
            };

            using (var connection = _dbContext.Database.Connection)
            {          
                connection.Open();
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(oracleParameters.ToArray());
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    oneEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                                .Translate<OneEntity>(reader)
                                                                                .ToList();
                    reader.NextResult();

                    twoEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                                .Translate<TwoEntity>(reader)
                                                                                .ToList();
                    reader.NextResult();

                    threeEntityList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
                                                                                .Translate<ThreeEntity>(reader)
                                                                                .ToList();
                }

                return new MyItems { OneEntity = oneEntityList, TwoEntity = twoEntityList, ThreeEntity = threeEntityList };
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct and proper to use `using` statements around disposable objects *when you own the lifetime*; however, in this case: you don't! The connection here belongs to the data-context, and presumably the data-context itself is `IDisposable`, and it will dispose the connection when *the data-context* is disposed.

So: while you might be allowed to *borrow* the connection from the data-context for the purposes of executing queries - you shouldn't be trying to *dispose* it here. That would end up closing/disposing a connection at unexpected times, with unpredictable results.

---

Conversely: if you had a `var conn = new OracleConnection(...)`, then clearly you *do* own *that* connection (unless you hand it to something that will manage the lifetime), and you *should* dispose it.

---

Just to complicate things further... currently, your `MyClass` seems to own the db-context, via:

```
private MyDbContext _dbContext = new MyDbContext();
```

So ideally, your `MyClass` should be disposable (`: IDisposable`), and disposing `MyClass` should cascade to dispose `_dbContext`.